# Trouble with Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

Everything appears to work. Not receiving any errors. Post request goes through successfully, but not receiving the email once the form is submitted

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'Gmail',
        auth: {
            user: '*********@gmail.com',
            pass: '*********',
        },
    });
    const name = req.body.name;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const message = req.body.message;
    const mail = {
        from: email,
        to: '*********@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Contact Form Message',
        html: `<p>Name: ${name}</p><p>Message: ${message}</p>`,
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mail, (error) => {
        if (error) {
            res.json({ status: 'failed' });
        } else {
            res.json({ status: 'sent' });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution code:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

router.post('/send', (req, res) => {
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      port: 587,
      secure: false,
      auth: {
        user: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
        pass: 'xxxx'
      },
    });

    const name = req.body.name;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const message = req.body.message;
    const mail = {
        from: email,
        to: 'xyz@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Contact Form Message',
        html: `<p>Name: ${name}</p><p>Message: ${message}</p>`,
    transporter.sendMail(mail, (error) => {
        if (error) {
            res.json({ status: 'failed' });
        } else {
            res.json({ status: 'sent' });
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**you need to take care of two things here:**

1. Go here and enable less secure apps -
   https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
2. Disable Captcha temporarily -
   https://accounts.google.com/b/0/displayunlockcaptcha

It works for me this way.